# Quotient topology of the topology of uniform convergence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a locally compact and boundedly compact metric space. Consider $C(E)$ the continuous maps from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets. Now say that $f\sim g$ if $f-g\equiv const.$ then let $C(E)/\mathbb{R}=C(E)/\sim=\{\{f+c:c\in\mathbb{R}\}:f\in C(E)\}$. What topology do we have on this quotient space?

Usually one considers quotient spaces of normed spaces with the norm $||[f]||_{\sim,K}=\inf\{||f'||_{\infty,K}:f'\in [f]\}=\inf\{||f+c||_{\infty,K}:c\in\mathbb{R}\}$, where $[f]\in C(E)/\mathbb{R}$ is an equivalence class and $||.||_{\infty,K}$ is the sup-norm on a compact set $K\subseteq E$.

In [this](https://egg.epfl.ch/metriques/Bridson-Haefliger.pdf) book on page 267 (while considering a slightly different setting, so maybe we can focus on $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ for now) they claim that a sequence of equivalence classes $[f_n]$ converges to $[f]$ if and only if there is a sequence $c_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n+c_n\to f$ uniformly on all compact (in their case bounded) sets. I can certainly see that if the infimum is attained, which it is on compact sets, one obtains such a minimizing sequence of constants $c_n\in\mathbb{R}$ but what about the opposite? Is this quotient norm not the right way to obtain the topology on the quotient space here?

Comment: Aren’t all “boundedly compact spaces” (Heine-Borel spaces) trivially locally compact too? I’m not sure why you stated both hypotheses

Comment: quotient spaces of a normed space aren’t necessarily normed spaces themselves. “Normally…”: we give a canonical norm to a quotient space when the quotient is a quotient by a closed subspace. That’s not what’s going on here, so, you can’t necessarily expect to do the same thing and get the same quotient topology

Comment: @FShrike That's what I thought too. However, the authors of another paper put it that way, so I kept it. But technically, every closed ball in a boundedly compact space should be a compact neighborhood of its center point. Regarding your other comment, formally we just divide out the closed subspace of constant functions, so it should be fine.

Comment: Wait, that was silly. I thought this wasn’t a quotient-by-subspace but it actually is